# Not centered horizontally because of position absolute

Tags: html, css

I made this:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header" >
</div>
<div id="main" >
</div>
<div id="footer" >
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    margin:0px;
}
#header
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    height:60px;
}
#main
{
    width:300px;
    border:1px dotted black;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#footer
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VpwQQ/2/

But as you can see, the `main` div doesn't have a height.

Then I replaced my css by that:

```
body
{
    margin:0px;
}
#header
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    height:60px;
}
#main
{
    width:300px;
    border:1px dotted black;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
    bottom:60px;
    top:80px;
}
#footer
{
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    height:40px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VpwQQ/1/

But then, the horizontal center doesn't work.

How can I do this design (div centered and that takes all the page in height between the header and footer with a 20 px magin) ?

Comment: You will have to use Javascript to center the div. Absolute position removes the element from the flow of the document.

Comment: @laymanje If don't want especially to use `position:absolute;`. I just want to do this design. (It's the same as stackoverflow and a lot of other website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I'll give my explaination of what's going to happen with your code:

Your #main div doesn't have a height because it doesn't have a height CSS property, nor does it have any content.

You should add either a `height: 100px` or just add some content and you will see it gets a height.

The reason why I ask what you want to do is because you're not very clear as to what you want your final product to look like.

You're going to have another problem with the footer. If you use position absolute it sticks to the bottom at the moment. Set the height of the #main div to something ridiculously high and you'll see that when you have to scroll down the page the footer stays where it is. See http://jsfiddle.net/VpwQQ/3/

You should use `position: fixed` but this will keep it on the bottom of the WINDOW and not the DOCUMENT. So then you get into the problem of having to use Javascript in order to measure the document height and setting positions appropriately. Not sure what you're trying to do, but if you're just trying to lay out a website then use standard relative positioning to push the footer down naturally below the #main div.

**Edit:**

See http://jsfiddle.net/VpwQQ/4/ if you're just trying to set up a normal website layout.

If you want the footer to "stick" to the bottom of the page all the time then you will need to use `position: fixed` but I don't think this works across all browsers. See http://jsfiddle.net/VpwQQ/6/

Lastly, to get both footer and header to "stick" see http://jsfiddle.net/VpwQQ/8/

Comment: I just want to have this design, like stackoverflow's design or facebook's design. A header and a footer, and an extensible main div. (And without JS).

Comment: The element doesn't need a `height` style to get a height, as it has a `top` and `bottom` style.

Comment: @guffa the element shouldn't have a height, nor a top and bottom style. In my first post I was explaining that the reason there is no height is because there is no content/height CSS value. However in a real world example the #main div will get its height from its content.

Comment: That's where you are wrong. The element needs neither a height style nor content to have a height, as it has both a top and bottom style.

Comment: @Guffa not in the OP's http://jsfiddle.net/VpwQQ/2/ example... there's no top no bottom and no height. :)

Comment: @ThomasClayson: Example two was added later (above the first example). In the first example there is a top and bottom style, and the element has a height.

Answer (score 1):

I added a div inside #main.

Main now has a 100% width.

Inside, put a div of 300px, with no absolute position.

I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8U9P6/

Personnally I prefer the javascript solution and not using the absolute position. But this solution seems to work.

Add and overflow to contain the content in the inside div: http://jsfiddle.net/M2nZc/

Note that the page will not grow as it is absolute position.

Comment: unludo, is there any reason to do all that work and not just to add a height to #main?

Comment: @Mageek then you have to use an overflow.

Comment: @ThomasClayson This solution works for resize, not if you set a fixed height

Comment: @ThomasClayson,  Mageek says there will be an extensible main div.. so thats why.

Comment: Yep... but extensible based on content. A div (unless otherwise set in the CSS) will grow to fit its content. I wasn't suggesting that there should be a height for the OP, what I was asking was why go to all the trouble to add another div, have divs inside divs, set top and bottom values etc... when exactly the same layout can be achieved using relative positioning. (And adding a height to #main in order to SHOW Mageek what effect it will have).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use automatic margins on an absolutely positioned element, as it's not in the document flow any more.

Use `width: 100%` on the `#main` div, then put another element inside it that you center using automatic margins.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/VpwQQ/9/

Note: You may need to use `height: 100%` on the `body` and `html` elements for the `bottom` sizing to work on the `#main` element.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fill your #main div with content, it will automatically gain height according to the content. You can simply fill it with a few paragraphs of [lorem ispum](http://en.lipsum.com/) to simulate content. You can now remove the absolute position and positioning CSS.

Centering a div using the "0 auto" shorthand only works when the parent element (which, for the #main div, is the body element) has a defined width. To do this, try giving your body element a width of 100%. Doing this is something that you might want to make a habit of in you CSS.

To have your #main div always be 20px below the #header div, simply add 20px of margin-bottom to your #header div. Do the same below the #main div to space the footer.

Summed up (without the footer at the bottom, for now) your CSS might read something like this:

```
body {
  width: 100%
  margin: 0px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px; /*here we space the header 20px from the next element*/
  background-color: black;

}

#main {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto; /*we append the margin to include 20px of spacing at the bottom*/
  border:1px dotted black;
}

#footer {
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WEx3j/

If you want the footer to be 'sticky' (always be at the very bottom of your website), I advise you to employ [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) method.

I hope this clarified a few things.